# Does a person have legal recourse if a drone is trespassing?

Tags: united-states, privacy, trespass, ohio, drones

I have a 10 foot privacy fence around my property. There are no trespassing signs on all four sides. One of the neighbors keeps flying a drone over my yard like they are casing the place.

Do I have any legal rights concerning such invasions?

Comment: Not a simple question, it turns out.

Comment: Take up kite-flying as a hobby. "Oops, your drone got caught on my kite string and seems to have landed in my pond".

Comment: How low is it flying? Are they also using it for any commercial applications? If the latter, you could check on whether they're licensed.

Comment: two words: water pistol

Comment: It depends on how high the dron flies. The space up to certain height is yours, so when the dron is within it you could get the operator charged with trespassing.

Comment: The problem is most country's including  the united states hasn't determined what air space is the property owners.  The FAA who is suppose to be setting up guide line is dragging their feet. By the time it is actually established no one will have any privacy left.

Answer (score 3):

[Boggs v. Merideth](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/4620147/boggs-v-merideth/) was a pretty big case involving private drones and the privacy of neighbors. Happened in Kentucky, though. I would suggest taking a look at that.

Comment: Doesn't Really help case was dismissed before it actually went to court. It was also more on the drones operators right to compensation than the land owners rights from intrusion. It also failed to cover discharging a fire arm in the air on all but 2 days of the year in most places is illegal. Guess I will half to build a F 16 to argue border skirmish against a hostile invader to shoot it down. Since the laws seem to be ignoring most people rights to a certain amount of privacy even when you do every thing you are suppose to do.

Comment: I understand your frustration. Really, I did an assignment on this topic for school and found that laws regarding drones and privacy are... mostly missing. /:

Comment: I think the one loop hole that protects people from drones is a FAA rule. think its 49 registration process. Drones are not allowed within 500 feet of a person,structure,home or emergency response worker. By that definition in the city's a drone should be what property owners would call land locked. It is against the rules to fly higher than 500 feet, so the second you fly over a person or a home you have just broke the FAA rules if you didn't have the owners permission. The real question is whether the rule extends to the road way if its closer than 500 feet to the home or structures

Answer (score 0):

The FAA regulations for non-commercial unmanned aircraft systems (UAS, commonly called drones) make no mention of privacy, flying near houses, or flying over other people's property. Some states have adopted regulations on UAS. A quick glance at a couple of them seem to reveal they are not regulating the operation itself, but other ancillary issues such as taking pictures without someone's consent.

INAL, but it would seem that if someone was operating a UAS legally under FAA rules, it would be hard to argue that the state had the legal authority to regulate airspace use when the FAA owns the airspace in question.

A website showing state-by-state laws is located [here](https://www.findlaw.com/consumer/consumer-transactions/drone-laws-by-state.html#:%7E:text=Civil%20Code%20Section%201708.8%3A%20Prohibits,of%20between%20%245%2C000%20and%20%2450%2C000.).

Comment: "it would seem that if someone was operating a UAS legally under FAA rules, it would be hard to argue that the state had the legal authority to regulate airspace use when the FAA owns the airspace in question": if FAA rules allow operation of aircraft at an altitude as low as 1 foot, that can't supersede state trespassing laws; otherwise, a trespasser could gain lawful access to someone's property by using e.g. a hovercraft.  The courts may not have defined it yet, but there must be a limit to the ability of aircraft to approach private property, even if the FAA doesn't set that limit.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, what does the FAA say about using a (crewed) helicopter to hover above your neighbor's property?  Does altitude matter?  If there are restrictions, why don't they apply to drones?  If there are no restrictions in the FAA regulations, wouldn't state law be able to regulate the behavior of those in the helicopter -- or of those operating the drone?

Comment: Here's the Federal Aviation Regulation on helicopter altitude operations: An altitude of 500 feet above the surface, except over open water or sparsely populated areas. In those cases, the aircraft may not be operated closer than 500 feet to any person, vessel, vehicle, or structure.

Comment: In contrast, non-commercial UAS operations cannot exceed 400' above ground level (AGL).

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER: Torts of TRESPASS and NUISANCE

Plaintiff may ask court to enjoin defendant from flying drone over plaintiff's property and may seek money damages.

"One of the neighbors keeps flying a drone over my yard" Complaint

"It has long been settled that a trespass to real property takes place not only on the surface, but also with any intrusion above or below the surface of the land." Smith v. Smith, 110 Mass. 302 (1872)

a “nuisance [is] … ‘a nontrespassory invasion of another’s interest in the private use and enjoyment of land.’ Restatement (Second) of Torts §821D.”

There are other definitions of nuisance. This definition may not apply in where you live. This the general principle. You should be able to complain to the police.

Comment: This can't stand as an answer on its own.

Comment: How does flying a drone invade a person's interest in enjoying their property. Is walking while ugly a similar invasion of that interest?

Comment: First, the drone is over his property, not flying over his neighbor's property. Don't you think you'd have a problem using your property if a drone was flying over it? and possibly you or another person or a pet or your car or some other valuable object? - No walking while ugly isn't similar. But noise can be a nuisance, even though no physical object of the defendant's is near the plaintiff's property.

Comment: The protection in California is for people “engaging in a private, personal or familial activity and the invasion occurs in a manner that is offensive to a reasonable person.” Cal. Civ. Code § 1708.8. Florida has a similar statutory claim. F.S.A. § 934.50. Nevada and Oregon allow for a “trespass” action if a drone flies over someone’s property and the property owner previously told the drone operator the drone was not authorized to fly over the property. N.R.S. 493.103

Comment: "Meredith says it was hovering over his property ... Judge Ward says that since at least two witnesses could see the drone below the tree line, it was an invasion of privacy. ... Last week, state representative St. Onge pre-filed her drone harassment bill for the 2016 session. It says a person is guilty of harassment when they hover over or land on someone's property, or use a drone for no legitimate purpose, to commit acts that alarm or seriously annoy someone." https://www.wdrb.com/news/judge-dismisses-charges-for-man-who-shot-down-drone/article_b52eff9b-0c87-53ce-ad68-38806c7c9288.html

Comment: Drone Lawsuits & Litigation Datagase 2019 https://jrupprechtlaw.com/drone-lawsuits-litigation/

Comment: @trish "*This can't stand as an answer on its own.*" Why not?